# How can I add an image onto Carrierwave using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, activerecord, amazon-s3

I am creating a photo web application. I have access to an amazon s3 bucket that contains all the photos I need in order to create my app. So far, I have everything set up correctly with `AWS` and `Carrierwave` to upload images to the cloud. However, I'm having a difficult time trying to do the opposite. I want to download the files from s3 and create `Person` objects in my database. I have constructed a custom rake task that attempts to do such a task. Here is the rake task:

```
desc 'Populate database with person s3 photos'
task migrate_s3_photos_to_db: :environment do
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'], credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY"], ENV['AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_Key'])
  s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).objects.each do |person|
    name = person.key.gsub('.jpg', '').gsub('_',' ')
    email = "#{name.scan(/\w+/)[0][0].downcase}" + "#{name.scan(/\w+/)[1].downcase}" + "@gmail.com"

    ===================Problem==========================
    Person.create(name: name, email: email, avatar: ?????????)
  end
end
```

The problem with the above task is that I'm not sure what I'm supposed to place into the avatar field. I've tried `person.key` which will result in the string of the image name (`Andy Johnson.jpg`). This doesn't work though.

I've also tried to create a `PersonAvatarUploader` that carrierwave provided but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate a s3 url for every object and pass it to  `remote_avatar_url` attribute:

```
s3_url = person.url_for(:read)
Person.create(name: name, email: email, remote_avatar_url: s3_url)
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html